# Sorting output from a while loop in Python 3

Tags: python, while-loop

The following code prints out number sequences up to around 100 from a list. A fair amount of the sequences print out above 100. I want to know how to only print out the numbers that add up to 100 on the button. I have tried printing the results to a list without luck. I tried putting in if and else statements to filter the results but with no luck. I looked at list comprehensions but I know those don't use while loops and so I don't know how to get the same results with a for loop. The only information I can seem to find online is basic lessons on how to use a while loop and just printing a list of numbers out. I could not find anything about how to sort a list of numbers printed.

Here is the code:

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in list1:
    a = 0
    num1 = 2
    num2 = i
    seq = ([a])
    it = itertools.cycle((num1,num2))
    while a < 100:
        a += next(it)
        print(a, end = " ")
        seq.append(a)
    print()    
    print("Here are the numbers", num1, "&", num2, "added together in a sequence")
    print()
```

Output:

```
2 3 5 6 8 9 11 12 14 15 17 18 20 21 23 24 26 27 29 30 32 33 35 36 38 39 41 42 44 45 47 48 50 51 53 54 56 57 59 60 62 63 65 66 68 69 71 72 74 75 77 78 80 81 83 84 86 87 89 90 92 93 95 96 98 99 101 
Here are the numbers 2 & 1 added together in a sequence

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 2 added together in a sequence

2 5 7 10 12 15 17 20 22 25 27 30 32 35 37 40 42 45 47 50 52 55 57 60 62 65 67 70 72 75 77 80 82 85 87 90 92 95 97 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 3 added together in a sequence

2 6 8 12 14 18 20 24 26 30 32 36 38 42 44 48 50 54 56 60 62 66 68 72 74 78 80 84 86 90 92 96 98 102 
Here are the numbers 2 & 4 added together in a sequence

2 7 9 14 16 21 23 28 30 35 37 42 44 49 51 56 58 63 65 70 72 77 79 84 86 91 93 98 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 5 added together in a sequence

2 8 10 16 18 24 26 32 34 40 42 48 50 56 58 64 66 72 74 80 82 88 90 96 98 104 
Here are the numbers 2 & 6 added together in a sequence

2 9 11 18 20 27 29 36 38 45 47 54 56 63 65 72 74 81 83 90 92 99 101 
Here are the numbers 2 & 7 added together in a sequence

2 10 12 20 22 30 32 40 42 50 52 60 62 70 72 80 82 90 92 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 8 added together in a sequence

2 11 13 22 24 33 35 44 46 55 57 66 68 77 79 88 90 99 101 
Here are the numbers 2 & 9 added together in a sequence

2 12 14 24 26 36 38 48 50 60 62 72 74 84 86 96 98 108 
Here are the numbers 2 & 10 added together in a sequence
```

What I want is:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 2 added together in a sequence

2 5 7 10 12 15 17 20 22 25 27 30 32 35 37 40 42 45 47 50 52 55 57 60 62 65 67 70 72 75 77 80 82 85 87 90 92 95 97 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 3 added together in a sequence

2 7 9 14 16 21 23 28 30 35 37 42 44 49 51 56 58 63 65 70 72 77 79 84 86 91 93 98 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 5 added together in a sequence

2 10 12 20 22 30 32 40 42 50 52 60 62 70 72 80 82 90 92 100 
Here are the numbers 2 & 8 added together in a sequence
```

Any and all help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you only know if your sequence addition adds up to 100 once you are done, so you can't start printing before that point. This should do the job:

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in list1:
    a = 0
    num1 = 2
    num2 = i
    seq = ([a])
    it = itertools.cycle((num1,num2))
    while a < 100:
        a += next(it)
        seq.append(a)
    if seq[-1] == 100:  # -1 as an index gets the last entry in a list
        print(" ".join([str(val) for val in seq]))  
        print("Here are the numbers", num1, "&", num2, "added together in a sequence")
        print()
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I run that change.

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in the line with the `join` command, I forgot it only accepts a list of strings, so the content of the list of ints needs to be converted into strings first